# How can I design a glamour spell for a creature that meets certain requirements?

Tags: magic, fantasy-races, balancing-magic-systems

The malcubi are demons from hell that consume people's souls during the act of intercourse. They have lived on earth since the days of early Mesopotamia, devouring men to feed their hunger and sustain themselves. In myths of the malcubi, they secrete a powerful hormone that acts as an aphrodisiac to attract victims. However, the truth is that they use a form of mental manipulation called "glamour" on their targets, making feeding easier. The spell flows into the body's aura where it then radiates its intent outwards to other minds within a certain radius. It is a mixture of magic and hypnotic suggestion, and is a permanent part of the creature's biology.

I need to design this glamour in a way that allows this creature to hunt, while fulfilling certain parameters. All onlookers should see their idealized vision of the perfect mate, which would be different for everyone. Even if they consciously don't know what that is, their subconscious desires must be met in that vision. However, this creature must be able to operate in public and avoid suspicion from society or perceptive individuals.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: So the scientific explanation is a *myth* while the truth is they use magic? :D Nice inversion of tropes.

Comment: Could you define what you need from us? currently i'd answer: "the magic needs to make it so All onlookers should see their idealized vision of the perfect mate, which would be different for everyone. Even if they consciously don't know what that is, their subconscious desires must be met in that vision. However, this creature must be able to operate in public and avoid suspicion from society or perceptive individuals."  ---  cause, you see, MAGIC.

Answer (score 2):

Cheat?

Very few people have clearly defined "vision of ideal mate" and pretty much nobody is stubborn enough about it to resist magic for it.

So simply have an aura that has people think that you match their preferences to perfection even if it differs what they thought their preferences are before they met you.

This is in every way simpler to do than changing perceived appearance and does not introduce any contradictions for people to spot as long as it is subtle enough to not override their own thinking.

And to be honest since all you want is regular sex, it is even simpler. The aura just has to suggest that they want to have sex with you. Human mind will do the rest without any kind of meddling unless there is a specific reason to not have sex with you. This should be rare enough to have no real impact on the food supply and as a side benefit makes conspicuously odd or inappropriate conquests less likely so the amount of risk will decrease.

Answer (score 1):

**What you want is for each individual man to think the attraction is only happening to him.  And for no one to notice anyone else being *abnormally* attracted.**

If a female-appearing demon walks by and suddenly 90% of the men within 10 feet start throwing themselves at her feet, that's a problem.  The women will notice.  The unaffected men will notice.  The children will know something's up.  And the men who are affected will realize this isn't normal.  (I'm assuming from your description and word choices that the malcubi only affect men and that they will take the form that each man desires, which can be either gender.  If I'm wrong, my answer won't change, just the genders used in my examples.)

So allow the glamour to work on every possible target.  Each man sees his ideal mate and is attracted.  Some of the men might be moved to talk to the demon but most will consider it a passing fancy and go about their business.  When they get out of range, the desires are just a memory.

But have a separate level of glamour that is directional and only works at a much smaller range.  The demon can turn it on and off at will.

A demon that wishes to hunt might walk through an area with multiple targets.  She'll (or he'll) assess the possibilities based on multiple factors, just like any hunter will before choosing a target.  What level of attraction does he have to her?  Is he pliable?  Is he alone?  Easy to lure to a secluded spot?  Will he make a good meal?

She may speak to him and see what he does.  Any onlooker would assume they are flirting and nothing more.  Or they might think she's a prostitute engaging a client.  Either way, no one will think there's anything supernatural going on.

Once the demon culls the man from the herd, takes him away from prying eyes, she can work her magic on him with the close-range glamour.  Now he is smitten and will do anything for her.  But there is no one around to see and get suspicious.  No one to save him.

Answer (score 0):

From OP /The spell flows into the bodies aura where it then radiates it's intent outwards to other minds within a certain radius/

Your solution is built into the ability.  If her intent is to get busy you will know it.  Your wingman will probably perceive that is her intent too.  But if her intent is to make delicious meatball subs, you will know that too, as will your wingman; this aside from the toasted cheese smell.

This ability need not be limited to seduction.  It will serve equally well to keep the demon inconspicuous when that is its desire.  The persuasive powers of these demons would be greatly helpful in other endeavors the demon might undertake to improve its resources or position in the world.  The sex magic aspect might only be occasional.

Answer (score 0):

Do not underestimate the power of pheromones. A powerful chemical produced by creatures that, once received by a target, interacts with the targets body, producing a hormonal response.

In this case, your demon would not necessarily need to disguise herself as, if the pheromone is strong enough, men would willingly fall for the malcubi's trap. They may even go willingly, knowing they would die afterwards. Because men could do stupid crap when their testosterone is pumping. Especially when sex is involved.